Spring Boot Admin: How to ignore sporadic DOWN responses from clients and keep status in UP?
Goal: The health actuators of our microservices include ping tests to external services. Naturally, these ping requests sometimes time out or fail for other reasons, which leads to a DOWN response by the /health actuator. We would like SBA Server to ignore 1-2 of those DOWN requests and keep the status for the service in UP, until let's say 3 or more DOWN responses were received.
I studied all the available configuration options for SBA Server but to be honest, I am confused how they all play together, and how I can achieve this goal. I naively thought the default-retries setting would accomplish this, but it didn't. I assume (hope) the desired behavior can be achieved by properly concerting multiple of those values, as it doesn't seem there is a single one that would achieve this goal.
For reference, these are the configuration options that I think may apply here:

spring.boot.admin.monitor.status-interval: Time interval to check the status of instances.
spring.boot.admin.monitor.status-lifetime: Lifetime of status. The status won’t be updated as long the last status isn’t expired.
spring.boot.admin.monitor.default-timeout: Default timeout when making requests.
spring.boot.admin.monitor.default-retries: Default number of retries for failed requests.

Any thoughts?

My suggestion would be to adapt your actuator healthcheck, which does ping the external services, to cache the last ping responses and only return DOWN after a few consecutive timeouts.
This way spring boot admin stays simple and the logic for this special case is kept in the place were it actually belongs

Great and practical idea. In absence of other responses, you got the "answer".
